# Could AWS Wavelength - carrier gateway be converted to an internet gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Could AWS Wavelength - carrier gateway be converted to an internet gateway?

**In my use case**, my web app should be accessible on both the carrier network and the internet. Users on a carrier network will experience low latency, and users on the internet will experience latency as expected.

**What Worked:**
As expected, I am able to access my web app on the carrier network after setting up all necessary AWS resources. The AWS documentation for the same can be found below.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/wavelength/latest/developerguide/get-started-wavelength.html

**Here's what didn't work:**

It is not possible to access the same web application over the internet.